What does the `foo]` syntax mean for a git option? Or is this `git-clone` Synopsis missing `[`s?
The git-clone doc has the following synopsis
git clone [--template=<template-directory>]
      [-l] [-s] [--no-hardlinks] [-q] [-n] [--bare] [--mirror]
      [-o <name>] [-b <name>] [-u <upload-pack>] [--reference <repository>]
      [--dissociate] [--separate-git-dir <git-dir>]
      [--depth <depth>] single-branch] [--no-tags]
      [--recurse-submodules[=<pathspec>]] shallow-submodules]
      remote-submodules] [--jobs <n>] [--sparse] reject-shallow]
      [--filter=<filter-spec>] [--also-filter-submodules]] [--] <repository>
      [<directory>]

I see several options w/ missing [s / unpaired ]s. They are

single-branch]
shallow-submodules]
remote-submodules]
reject-shallow]
[--also-filter-submodules]]

Is foo] a special syntax? Or are these options missing [s?

I think those are just typos in the docs
https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L12-L20

For most of those I think it might be that it had a [[no] that maybe got edited out by accident e.g. --single-branch can also be used as --no-single-branch

I'd suggest filing a bug on the docs. In general these synopses are not as useful as they might be; they are not complete and they are darned hard to read under the best of circumstances.

@apokryfos I thought of that too - I noticed that all the ones that have this problem have no- alternates. You've probably hit on it.

I reported this bug to the Git mailing list, link here
